# TypeError: DisplayMarketingMessage() takes no arguments how to fix it

Tags: html, css, django, python-3.x

## this is my code stuff where i am getting error ,

when i am going to execute it
i want to create custom middleware .

```
from marketing.models import MarketingMessage

class DisplayMarketing():
    def process_request(self,request):
        try:
            request.session['marketing_message']=MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
        except:
            request.session['marketing_message']=False
```

Comment: DisplayMarketing(View)

Comment: what are you trying to say? please explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following implimentation

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class DisplayMarketing(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            request.session['marketing_message']=MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
        except:
            request.session['marketing_message']=False
```